# Polynomial P= Q² + R²

Tags: polynomials

I want to show that every polynomial $P$ $(\geq0)$ can be written with two other polynomials $Q$ and $R$. $$P=Q^2+R^2$$

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: If the polynomial is positive, and in one variable, then yes.

Comment: Important added condition: one variable!

Comment: I believe you should better describe your conditions. $(\geq 0)$ isn't understandable.